# i.atcorr - Landsat 8

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I am trying to apply atmospheric correction to Landsat 8 scenes using `i.atcorr`. After tons of tests I am still struggling with the correct input and output range.
The results deriving from radiance as input and from reflectance as input are different!
I have radiance and reflectance from `i.landsat.toar` and try to get the `i.atcorr` results. I try several combination of input and output range and the only ones that seem to produce a nice RGB are:
Input: the full range of radiance (Lmin, Lmax)
Output: 0,1 or the full range of reflectance (computed by dividing Lmin and Lmax by the factor that converts radiance to reflectance and is computed by `i.landsat.toar`)
Or in case of reflectance
Input: Lmin, Lmax divided by the convertion factor mentioned above
Output: the same as radiance

In both cases the resulting values are different which cannot be correct (Radiance and reflectance should produce the same outcome) and when I examine the resulting RGB, the result is almost exactly the same as the digital number image before the atmospheric correction.

Does anyone really uses `i.atcorr` to perform atmospheric correction to Landsat? And if so, which is the right way (input/output range)?

Comment: Your question is attracting close votes for "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based". Maybe if you included what values you have tried and why you think they're not working, someone might have an answer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: To narrow the question, which is the correct input and output range, in order for the module to work. And for that combination I suppose the outcome from the radiance as input and for the reflectance as input will give the same resulting image, right?